# How to find bitshift between two numbers

Tags: java, math, bit-shift

I am trying to find the bitshift operators required to do a specific transformation

```
50381044488375 > 630
50376749521075 > 629
50398224357551 > 628
50389636520755 > 632
```

All of these transformations are done with the same bithift/bitoperator. `50389636520755L >> 3 & 0x7FF` was suppose to work but it is giving me 870.  Am I able to find the proper bitshift between these numbers?

Comment: Can you give some context on what you are trying to achieve, and what you've tried so far?

Comment: Evidently `50381044488375 > 630` is not stating or asking if  50381044488375 is greater than 630. So what does it mean?

Answer (score 2):

Most of the bits for these numbers are the same, so let's start by writing them out in binary, and highlighting all the bits where they are different:

10110111010**010**0100000001**0**00010100110**001**01**101**11 → 100111**0110**
10110111010**001**0100000001**0**00010100110**001**01**100**11 → 100111**0101**
10110111010**110**0100000001**0**00010100110**001**01**011**11 → 100111**0100**
10110111010**100**0100000001**1**00010100110**110**01**100**11 → 100111**1000**

We would like to find shifts which map columns from the left onto columns on the right. The first and second columns on the right (01,01,01,10) can be found on the left, as can the fourth column on the right (0,1,0,0), but the third column on the right (1,0,0,0) does not exist on the left, so we will need to form it by some operation on two columns on the left. Fortunately we can find two columns (1,1,0,1) and (1,0,1,0) whose bitwise `&` is what we require.

So a full solution is like this:

```java
long mapping(long x) {
    return 0b1001110000                // the constant output bits
        | (x >> 5) & 0b1100            // first two output bits
        | (x >> 3) & (x >> 1) & 0b0010 // third output bit
        | (x >> 32) & 0b0001;          // fourth output bit
}
```

Comment: Since the question is unclear to me I'm having trouble understanding the answer. Can you clarify what you think the questioner is asking for?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Seems clear to me; the question is asking for a transformation from the numbers on the left to the numbers on the right, using bitwise operations.

Comment: @kaya3 well, they said too must to be of the form `50389636520755L >> 3 & 0x7FF`...

Comment: @josejuan No, they said that's what they tried but it didn't work.

Comment: _"was suppose to work"_ is more than a try but is clear to me too this is a unclear question, the only way to answer (imho) is generalizing providing the general way to derive the map function (e.g. why not use division? you are using `|` xD )

Comment: @josejuan Well, the question is clear to me whether or not it is clear to you; and my answer *did* explain the process by which I derived the mapping.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a [Boolean Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_expression), you simply could derive the truth table (one for every output bit) using some library as [LogicNG](https://github.com/logic-ng/LogicNG). The process to follow is

- name every input bit `x0`, `x1`, ... (for `long` values up to `x63`).
- for every output bit `r0`, `r1`, ... get a boolean expression as follows

  - use every input number `N` to form a row of the [Truth Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table)
  - the bit result for that row is the `r-th` bit for the result value for the input `N`
- once you get every `r-th` boolean expression from the truth tables, join all of them using `OR` replacing every `x-th` variable with `(x << th)` and you'll get one unique boolean expression.

Note: your example is `0x270L | (15 & (n / 449 - n / 763))`, yes, dividing by a constant is "directly" transformable to a bit operation https://embeddedgurus.com/stack-overflow/2009/06/division-of-integers-by-constants/